# Teams notifications are not received when using Graph's sendActivityNotification

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I've created a Teams app using the Teams App Visual Studio template, and configured it with a single personal tab. I've set set up ngrok so that this can be debugged locally. I've sideloaded the app, and all looks fine - Teams can load the tab, and it displays as it should.

I'm now trying to send an [activity notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/userteamwork-sendactivitynotification?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) to this tab. Graph accepts the post activity just fine - I'm returned a 204 - but the activity is never delivered to my Teams client.

My test teams user and the Azure AD app are configured in the same tenant. The Azure AD app has the TeamsActivity.Send permission.

All URLs in my manifest are configured with the ngrok endpoint. I have a valid activityType defined, and my webApplicationInfo section is configured with the AAD App ID and redirect URI as outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-send-activityfeednotifications). I've also added TeamsActivity.Send to the applicationPermissions section of webApplicationInfo

I'm posting the following json to Graph:

```
{
    'topic': {
        'source': 'entityUrl',
        'value': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/<my user id>/teamwork/installedApps/<my app id>'
    },
    'activityType': 'testActivity',
    'previewText': {
        'content': 'Something happened'
    },
    'templateParameters': [
        {
            'name': 'teammember',
            'value': 'Bobby muffin'
        }
    ]
}
```

This all ties up correctly with the manifest, and as I mentioned, Graph accepts the POST just fine. I've also tried adding the "recipient" section to the json, but get the same result.

I have no idea why I'm not seeing notifications. After I post the notification, I don't see any traffic to ngrok (although I'm not sure whether the notification would come in that way, or via the Teams client).

It feels like I'm missing some config somewhere.

Comment: (1) If you dont see any traffic with ngrok then it's suspicious; you may want to check its config (2) As a sanity check you can do this - for the given channel/teams the notifications (Channel notification set as off, at your client) are not turned off, right?

Comment: I’m using the user notifications (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/userteamwork-sendactivitynotification?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) rather than channel/team notifications. In the client, I have all my notifications turned up to the max. I see traffic to Ngrok when the tab loads, so the config seems fine - just not when I send a notification request to Graph. Would you expect activity notification to come into the app via ngrok, or directly into Teams?

Comment: I'm faced with the same situation as you. The response of the request is "204 No Content" and seems ok but I don't see the any notification on my Teams client. I've tried it with the desktop client and the browser client with turning on the installation of the preview version. Now I'm thinking it might be a bug since it's beta endpoint. Another thought is that they haven't provide the version of the client supporting notification functionality, because their document shows there is an setting option of the notification for each Teams App, but I don't see it on the setting of my Teams client.

Answer (score 0):

My bad... while I was testing this, I was trying to send a notification to myself, which is explicitly not supported - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-send-activityfeednotifications#faqs